# How to customize background color for some web pages opened with eww?

Tags: themes, eww

I just installed emacs 24.4 and I've started using eww. But one annoying thing is that when I visit google.com I get a grey background which makes text really hard to read for my theme.

This is how it looks: [image]

Is there any way I could change the color of the background? I first thought I could customize eww faces but there is no option for this. I'm also curious why is this background color there, in the first place.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* the background color is there either, but it seems to be controlled by the function `shr-color-check`, which is supposed to check that the contrast between the fg and bg is sufficient for the text to be visible.  I agree that the readability is not very good in your example.  Luckily, there are some variables that can be tweaked: `shr-color-visible-luminance-min` and `shr-color-visible-distance-min`.  I tried setting

```
(setq shr-color-visible-luminance-min 70)
```

and the results are much more readable:

[image: Screenshot of eww window with better contrast]

Comment: Yep, using `shr-color-visible-luminance-min` makes the content of the page readable. Thanks.

Comment: I've had luck with those variables for gnus emails before, but then I came across emails where I actually had to *decrease*  the luminance-min to make things more readable (stupid AirBnB html), so eventually I just did `(advice-add #'shr-colorize-region :around (defun shr-no-colourise-region (&rest ignore)))`