# Different themes for text buffers vs ansi-term?

Tags: colors

I'd like to be able to use different color themes when I'm editing text versus when I'm using a terminal such as ansi-term. (Note: I'm not referring to different color schemes for GUI mode versus terminal mode). Is this possible? In general, is it possible to switch the color scheme on a per-buffer basis rather than global?

Comment: There are several threads regarding buffer-local themes, and also several threads regarding using `face-remap-add-relative` to make faces buffer-local.  Please try and distinguish your question so that it is not marked as a duplicate and closed.

Comment: If you can link me to some of these questions I'd appreciate it a great deal. It's not often easy to know what to search for. I wouldn't have the foggiest clue to search for `face-remap-add-relative`. As a person who uses emacs but isn't particularly interested in hacking it myself, I'd just like to get some information on the topic.

Comment: Here is a link to the primary library most frequently cited in threads dealing with buffer-local themes:  https://github.com/vic/color-theme-buffer-local  Here is a link to a thread that describes how to remap an arbitrary face on a buffer-local basis:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7283/2287  Here is a link to thread dealing with the same concept that remaps the `'default` face on a buffer-local basis, which is triggered by a major-mode hook -- you can replace that example hook with something like `text-mode-hook`:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28008006/2112489