# Set font for a specific file?

Tags: fonts

I'd like to always display one particular text file named "table.txt" in a monospaced font, while displaying all the other buffers in a variable-width font. How can I achieve this?

Edit: the suggested link doesn't have the code block solution in the answer below, and the code block seems to work best for this purpose (**always** displaying a particular buffer in some face), so I don't think this counts as a duplicate?

Comment: Ah, I thought this seemed familiar. Possible duplicate of [How to modify-face for a specific buffer?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/how-to-modify-face-for-a-specific-buffer)

Comment: Isn't that for a one-time change? By "always", I meant I wanted to associate a particular text file with some face, and for that purpose the code block you posted seems to work best. Maybe I'll edit my question.

Comment: I think you were really looking for two things: (a) that related Q&A; and (b) how to make (any) setting file-local. Having two Q&As for every problem (with and without file-local variables) would seem inefficient :) But that's ok -- until you have the answers, it's not always clear that there were multiple questions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe use a buffer-local value for `face-remapping-alist` to remap `default` to something else in that one buffer?

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Face Remapping` <kbd>RET</kbd>

e.g.:

```el
(face-remap-add-relative 'default :family "Monospace")
```

or in a file-local variable block.

e.g.:

```
;; Local Variables:
;; eval: (face-remap-add-relative 'default :family "Monospace")
;; End:
```

Comment: Thanks! I was actually looking for a code block like that, but I forgot what to call it, so I didn't mention it particularly in my question. I tried that code block and it works, but how can I skip the confirmation where I need to type a "y" each time?

Comment: Is Emacs not offering/describing the `!` option when it prompts you?

Comment: Oh, yes! I chose it and it worked, thanks! I have trouble skimming English text really quickly: sorry for asking a really obvious question. :)