# Is it possible to change the font size in specific buffers?

Tags: buffers, fonts, customize

I would like to have different font sizes for the buffer windows in Emacs. That is, I would like to have a bigger font in the buffer where i write the code, and a smaller font in the buffer where i use the term to browse and run the scripts. Is it possible ?

Comment: Simple answer is to use `C-x C-+` (`text-scale-adjust`) in the given buffer.

Comment: See also `face-remap-add-relative`:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7283/2287

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use a hook:

```el
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda () (text-scale-decrease 1)))
```