# How can I make a theme use particular face attributes for a given face in a single buffer?

Tags: faces, themes

I'm loading a `deftheme` theme using `(load-theme)`. I'm very happy with it most cases, but in `yaml-mode` I'd like to change attributes for `font-lock-variable-name-face`.

How can I make the theme use different face attributes for it in a single buffer?

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/how-to-modify-face-for-a-specific-buffer and https://github.com/vic/color-theme-buffer-local

Comment: To use `face-remap-add-relative` in conjunction with a particular major-mode hook, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28008006/2112489

Comment: @lawlist Thank you! That works, and is much cleaner than a hacky override I cooked up with font-lock-add-keywords.

Comment: Please feel free to write up an answer at your convenience.  I don't have a setup that uses themes or `yaml-mode`, so I could not test anything and that is why I did not want to venture to write up an answer ...

Answer (score 0):

As @lawlist suggested I used `face-remap-add-relative` to achieve the required effect:

```
(add-hook 'yaml-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-variable-name-face :foreground "#fec66c")))
```