# How to define different font-lock-variable-name-face respect to different modes

Tags: major-mode, customize-face

By default `font-lock-variable-name-face` is defined as follows:

```lisp
'(font-lock-variable-name-face ((t (:foreground "black" :weight bold))))
```

Would it be possible to change its color for different modes such as for `shell-mode`:

I have tried the following, which did not have any effect:

```lisp
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            '(font-lock-variable-name-face ((t (:foreground "LightGoldenrod" :weight bold))))))
```

---

`dracula-theme.el` is located under `~/.emacs.d/themes`: https://github.com/dracula/emacs/blob/master/dracula-theme.el

minimal.el:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes")
(load-theme 'dracula t)

(defun my-shell-mode-faces ()
  (face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-variable-name-face '(:foreground "LightGoldenrod" :weight bold)))

(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'my-shell-mode-faces)
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of a shell command that produces output in a `shell-mode` buffer with the `font-lock-variable-name-face`?   I tried a few things like `make`, `ls`, `grep`, and `vi` of a few different files -- but none of those produce output with the `font-lock-variable-name-face`.

Comment: Ah I was just opening a file ending with `sh` like: `test.sh` . Its just a `Shell-script` file. Example file can contain something like: `#!/bin/bash

RED="\033[1;31m"` where `RED`should be  in `LightGoldenrod ` color

Comment: **STEP #1**:  Create a file called `test.sh`, with the first line being `#!/bin/bash  RED="\033[1;31m"`  **STEP #2**:  Open the file `test.sh` and place the cursor on the word `RED` in the first line and type `C-u C-x =` and a `*Help*` buffer pops up telling us that this is `font-lock-comment-face`.  **STEP #3**:  From the buffer containing the `test.sh` file, type `C-h m`, which is also known as `M-x describe-mode` -- this opens a `*Help*` buffer that tells us this is shell-script mode defined in `sh-script.el` -- follow the link for `sh-script.el` in the `*Help*` buffer ....

Comment: [... continued from previous comment] and we are transported to the definition for `sh-mode`.  Based thereon, we conclude that the major-mode hook we are interested in is `sh-mode-hook`.  **CONCLUSION**:   From steps 1 to 3 above, we learned that the face is `font-lock-comment-face` and the major-mode hook is `sh-mode-hook`.  Therefore, adjust the example in the answer below accordingly to suit your own needs using the relevant face and the relevant hook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My previous answer in this forum to a similar thread did not include an example using a major-mode hook [How to modify-face for a specific buffer?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/how-to-modify-face-for-a-specific-buffer) , so I chose to write up this new answer.

The function `face-remap-add-relative` sets the variable `face-remapping-alist` (responsible for buffer-local faces), which the manual recommends be set using the aforementioned function:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html

```lisp
(defun my-shell-mode-faces ()
  (face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-variable-name-face '(:foreground "LightGoldenrod" :weight bold)))

(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'my-shell-mode-faces)
```

Comment: I have tried it but it did not make any color change in the shell-mode :-( Could something overwrite into it? I was loading another theme before `(load-theme 'dracula t)`, seems like it prevents it ?

Comment: Before posting the answer, I tested it (Emacs 27, in a `shell-mode` buffer) with the `default` face to verify that it worked.  If you can come up with a minimal working example that produces the particular face at issue within a `shell-mode` buffer, either myself or another forum participant might be able to see what the problem might be.

Comment: Thanks, I was not able to figure out the problem :-( I have updated my question with the minimal.el. Basically I am loading `dracula-theme.el` right before applying your answer. Please note that I am using `emacs 26.3` but not sure its version will cause it