# Changing background colour when using Emacs Help

Tags: themes

Have got emacs running on a dark background.  Would like to change the background to orange colour when I am using Emacs Help.  Can this be done?

Comment: Try using the `help-mode-hook` and attach a function containing a call to `face-remap-add-relative`; e.g., `(add-hook 'help-mode-hook (lambda () (face-remap-add-relative ...)))`.  The face at issue is likely `default` and the spec is `:background`.  Does this answer your question? [How to modify-face for a specific buffer?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/how-to-modify-face-for-a-specific-buffer)

Comment: Answers it and managed to make it happen.