# How to change background color of a specific file?

Tags: themes, colors, eval

Let's say I want my file `notes.org` to have a specific background color. How to do that? But I want other files to adhere to the standard theme color for background.

So, I want yellow background for `notes.org` but the theme background color for everything else.

It should be something simple, but I can't find the way how to do it.

I would prefer a way I can set it via elisp code in my init (.spacemacs) file. Preferably without the need to create a custom theme just for one file etc.
The least favorite option is to put it in # Local Variables eval but if the only way it's possible is this way, I will be thankful for even that solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify-face for a specific buffer?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/how-to-modify-face-for-a-specific-buffer)  Perhaps try using something like the following code snippet and combine it with the same approach as in the accepted answer of the related linked thread:  `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (when (string-match "notes\\.org$" buffer-file-name) (face-remap-add-relative ...))))`  The face at issue is named `default` and the spec is `:background`.

Comment: @lawlist I have tried this: `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when
                (string-match "notes\\.org$" buffer-file-name)
              (face-remap-add-relative
               'stripe-highlight '(:foreground "black" :background "yellow")))))` but it is not working. The background is still white in notes.org. ;(

Comment: Why are you suggesting to close this question, when it is not working ;( ?

Comment: I can't find anywhere solution for this. Please, if somebody know what to do change in the code, let me know. Thank you.

Comment: The face name that you are interested in changing is called `default`.  The linked example uses the face name `stripe-highlight`.  Consider substituting the latter with the former ...

Comment: `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (when (and (not (null buffer-file-name)) (string-match-p "notes\\.org$" buffer-file-name)) (face-remap-add-relative 'default '(:foreground "black" :background "yellow")))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this

[image: Change color of just a single buffer]

do this

1. `C-x C-f somefile.org`
2. Add the following three lines to very end of file

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (face-remap-add-relative 'default :foreground "black" :background "yellow")
# End:
```

3. C-x C-s. Do `M-x revert-buffer RET`.
4. Profit.

---

If the file of interest is in some other mode, and not `org-mode` the above suggestion will not work.  In that case, use

```
M-x add-file-local-variable RET eval RET (face-remap-add-relative 'default :foreground "black" :background "yellow") RET
```

Save the file.  Kill the buffer.  Re-open the file.

Comment: Instead of killing the buffer and reopening it, just call `normal-mode`.

Comment: Yes.  Thanks.  Today I learnt about `normal-mode`.