# How to apply `load-theme-buffer-local` with "default" theme?

Tags: themes, eww

I used this answer to try to get eww to use more readable colours for me in my configuration, which uses the `monokai` theme:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3523/5495

That answer uses `load-theme-buffer-local`.  Using the answer as-is (with the `tango` theme) still gives different results than running eww from `emacs -q` (in particular, a darker background if I visit https://news.ycombinator.com/).

Is there a different theme name I can use here that will give results similar to what I get before applying any theme?  Or some other way to get an equivalent effect -- i.e. effectively not applying the monokai theme to eww buffers?

Comment: If you really like `eww` as opposed to other options such as `emacs-w3m`, then I would suggest two different possible approaches.  (1) You could have your custom themes load for each particular major-mode (i.e., you decide) on a `buffer-local` basis so as not to modify your *default theme* -- the *default theme* is not really a theme per se; instead, there are approximately 805 different face settings that come shipped with Emacs (e.g., grep for `defface` in the source code).  (2) You could familiarize yourself with the source code of `shr.el` and modify it to suit your personal taste.